# Trying to create optimized images for universal iOS development, where do I start?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image, photoshop

So I understand that in order to create a universal app and make it look good on all apple devices I need to make sure that I have multiple versions of each image.

What is the best way to go about doing this?
What are the resolutions that I need to use for each device?
Do I really need a separate image for the Iphone/Iphone 4/Iphone Retina/Iphone 5/Ipad/Ipad Retina?

I have all of the images in an .ai file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to know is here:

[iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

Comment: And don't forget to add the @2x for the retina device on your images

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 4 sets of images:

-iPhone 3g, iPod touch 2g, iPod touch 3g.

-iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPod touch 4, iPod touch 5.(retina)

-iPad 1,iPad 2.

-The new iPad.(retina)

**Create the highest resolution images first.**

[UIImage imageNamed:@"customBackground"];

You should have 2 images:

customBackground.png

customBackground@2x.png (retina display)

Comment: After playing around with this I realized I didn't know how to name my images. What's the best way to name them?